# Jenkins pipeline fails when checking out Jenkinsfile from github

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

When I try to run a job i am getting below error. 
can someone please tell me what is the issue and what is causing this?

Thank you

> 19:23:40 Connecting to https://api.github.com using NextCloudBees/****** (Github user used in multibranch pipeline. Should be able to create webhooks.)
>   ERROR: Could not do lightweight checkout, falling back to heavyweight
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jobs-jobadapter-service/666da490ed54297a9ab19a9dc6b37a7cf641bb23/Jenkinsfile?token=AMP7ZW2P73S43FT4XT3AP6S6E46TU
>   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
>   at  com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>   at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.asStream(Requester.java:340)
>   Caused: org.kohsuke.github.GHFileNotFoundException: 404: Not Found

Comment: what is the repo address in the configuration ?

Comment: Hello, the repo is private but address is like this https://github.com/my-company/devops-maven-testapp